# Hot to do subplots with ITM of trace32

Tags: plot, trace32

I am debugging a chip with trace32 .

I true to visualize many variables at the same plot.

When I do
Trace.Draw.Var %HEX Variable1 Variable2 Variable3 /Steps

I get something like
[image]

Note that above, I have used variable values of equal to 1 , 2 and 3 to make this look better, but its still not good enough.

I would prefer sth like subplot of Matlab, where one variable appears on top of the other, eg

[image]

How would that be possible in trace32?

Answer (score 0):

To have several plots which are somehow synced, you could open them one after another and use the option `/ZoomTrack` with each window. If you then click to one of your windows or change the scaling in one window, all the other windows with `/ZoomTrack` will follow.

For your example:

```
Trace.Draw.Var %HEX Variable1 /Steps /ZoomTrack
Trace.Draw.Var %HEX Variable2 /Steps /ZoomTrack
Trace.Draw.Var %HEX Variable3 /Steps /ZoomTrack
```

For a positioning of the windows from script use the command `WinPOS` or position your windows manually with your mouse and generate a script for this positioning with `STOre * WinPAGE`.